# Is there a Java equivalent to getchar?

Tags: java

I have a simple client server program, wherein I have a problem with my menu:

```
do {  
    System.out.println("---- MENU ----\n");  
    System.out.println("(drv) - List drives");  
    System.out.println("(pwd) - Current path");  
    System.out.println("(ls) - List files in a directory");  
    System.out.println("(quit) - Quit program\n");  
    System.out.print("Enter a command: ");  
    command = scanner.nextLine();  
    sendMessage(command);  
    message = (String)in.readObject();  
    System.out.println(message);  
    System.in.read();  
}while(!command.equals("quit"));`
```

I want to print the result on the screen, wait until I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then show the menu again, so I use `System.in.read()`. My problem is that it works the first time, but if I choose another option it doesn't print anything:

> ---- MENU ----
>
> (drv) - List drives
>   (pwd) - Current path
>   (ls) - List files in a directory
>   (quit) - Quit program
>
> Enter a command: pwd
>   D:\Documents and Settings\asname\workspace_java\server
>
> ---- MENU ----
>
> (drv) - List drives
>   (pwd) - Current path
>   (ls) - List files in a directory
>   (quit) - Quit program
>
> Enter a command: ls

Is there a method in Java similar to `getchar` that I could use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add  `scanner.nextLine();`  after `System.out.println(message);` so it waits